# why MongoDB returns a CastError when I am trying to delete an Item by id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I am trying to make the DELETE Rest API method but I get CastError.
The problem is with the id it's of type ObjectID and I made it as a number, even when I chose string I got the same error.

[image]

**Error**

```
[Nest] 15504  - 22/12/2021, 21:34:11   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ id: '61c32ba552a7cec272037b12' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "City"
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ id: '61c32ba552a7cec272037b12' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "City"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4594:21)
    at CitiesService.deleteCity (C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\src\cities\cities.service.ts:46:64)
    at CitiesController.deleteCity (C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\src\cities\cities.controller.ts:25:31)
    at C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

**cities.service.ts**

```
@Delete(':id')
async deleteCity(id) {
    const result = await this.cityModel.deleteOne({ _id: id }).exec();

    if (!result) {
      throw new NotFoundException('Could not find city.');
    }
  }
```

**cities.controller.ts**

```
@Delete(':id')
  deleteCity(@Param() id: number) {
    return this.citiesService.deleteCity(id);
  }
```

**city.model.ts**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const CitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  weather: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Mixed,
});

export interface City {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  weather: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed;
}
```

**city.entity.ts**

```
import { BaseEntity, Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class City extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  weather: any;
}
```

Comment: `id` in `deleteOne({ _id: id })` should be an instance of ObjectId https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/ Create one from the parameter in the controller and pass it to the service.

Comment: Can demonstrate it using code please?

Comment: I never used nestjs, in javascript it would be `oid = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);`.  You can actually try `this.cityModel.findByIdAndDelete` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndDelete says it accepts string id and does the conversion implicitly

Comment: Thank you @Alex I tried casting the id `const cityId = new ObjectId(id);` in the service and its working perfectly

Comment: Great stuff! Would you mind formatting it as an answer and accepting it to make it clear what the solution is to anyone who faces this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**cities.service.ts**

```
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';

...
@Delete(':id')
async deleteCity(id) {
    const cityId = new ObjectId(id); // Cast id to MongoDB Object id
    const result = await this.cityModel.deleteOne({ _id: cityId }).exec();

    if (!result) {
      throw new NotFoundException('Could not find city.');
    }
  }
```